# Error al conectar Symfony a MySQL

Tags: mysql, symfony

Tengo un proyecto Symfony que intento conectar con una bbdd. El MySQL lo tengo con WAMP.

El .env de Symfony lo tengo así y la contrasña y usuario de MySQL estan bien ya que desde PHPMyAdmin puedo entrar:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@dmin1234@127.0.0.1:3306/advSoftware
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Por consola, ubicado en el proyecto de Symfony pongo este comando
`php bin/console doctrine:database:create` pero me devuelve estos errores.

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:

  An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver  


In PDOConnection.php line 31:

  could not find driver  

In PDOConnection.php line 27:

  could not find driver  


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Si me pudieras ayudar, lo agradecería mucho.
Gracias.

Comment: Te está diciendo que no tiene el driver de php-mysql. Revisa como se instalan las extensiones de PHP en wamp y .irá como instalar php-mysql

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que no se encuentra habilitado la extensión de mysql en WAMP.
Para ello ubica el archivo de configuración de php: `php.ini`
Localiza la extensión dentro del archivo: `;extension=pdo_mysql`
y descomenta quedando así: `extension=pdo_mysql`

Guarda los cambios y reinicia el WAMP.